# /i18n/setlang/ only gets pt-br

Tags: python, django

i'm needing some help here, been trying to figure this the whole morning...i need to make internationalization for this website and i have settings and everything double-checked, po/mo files correctly in locale folder, but everytime i click "english" on the form it actually gets pt-br, as shown on cmd server log, and keeps on the same page, without translating!

i don't understand why it only gets pt-br, i've searched all over Google and even here, but i still can't get a solution!

in the view i'm testing with (last code snippet), it also only gets pt-br! i type in browser "localhost/set_language/en", it redirects to homepage but on cmd server log, it shows it's still pt-br!

i ran debuggs and it is correctly entering the 'if's!

i'm already out of ideas why it is only getting pt-br! i just started learning django recently, so if anyone could help me figure this out, i'd be really thankful!

p.s: the browser i'm testing with has language set to english!

here is the form code:

```html
{% load i18n %}

<ul>
    <li>
     <form name="setLangEnglish" method="post" action="/i18n/setlang/">{% csrf_token %}
         <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
         <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en"/>
         <input class="language-switcher" type="submit" alt="English" name="submit" value="English"/>
     </form>
    </li>
    <li>
     <form name="setLangPortuguese" method="post" action="/i18n/setlang/">{% csrf_token %}
      <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
      <input type="hidden" name="language" value="pt-br"/>
      <input class="language-switcher" type="submit" alt="Portugues" name="submit" value="Portugues"/>
     </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is settings.py:

```html
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'apps.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'apps.wsgi.application'

LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR.parent, 'locale/'))


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

   
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', u'Inglês'),
    ('pt-br', u'Português'),
    ('es', u'Espanhol'),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False
```

and here is the url.py:

```html
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^$', 'apps.noticia.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^set_language/(?P<language>.+?)/$', 'apps.noticia.views.set_language', name='set_language'),
    

    #url de terceiros
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), 
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^institucional/', include('apps.institucional.urls', namespace='institucional')),
    url(r'^ingresso/', include('apps.ingresso.urls', namespace='ingresso')),
    url(r'^ensino/', include('apps.ensino.urls', namespace='ensino')),
    url(r'^nucleos/', include('apps.nucleo.urls', namespace='nucleo')),
    url(r'^pesquisa/', include('apps.pesquisa.urls', namespace='pesquisa')),
    url(r'^extensao/', include('apps.extensao.urls', namespace='extensao')),
    url(r'^editais/', include('apps.edital.urls', namespace='edital')),
    url(r'^noticias/', include('apps.noticia.urls', namespace='noticia')),
    url(r'^eventos/', include('apps.evento.urls', namespace='evento')),
    url(r'^contato/', include('apps.contato.urls', namespace='contato')),
)
```

here is a view i was testing with:

```html
def set_language(request, language):

    from django.utils.http import is_safe_url
    from django import http

    response = http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

    lang_code = language
    if lang_code and check_for_language(lang_code):
        print 'asdsadsa'
        if hasattr(request, 'session'):
            print 'asddds'
            request.session['django_language'] = lang_code
            translation.activate(lang_code)
        else:
            response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, lang_code)

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use correct session key for language (`django.utils.translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY`) cause exactly this key is used to take current language code from session in `LocaleMiddleware` for all future http requests.

Also your html forms are incorrect cause they send language code in POST data but your url + view declarations expect that language code is located directly inside url. That's different approach. Why not to use django setlang view as is? Maybe you have problems to make it work, don't you?

P.S. I suggest you to remove your db credentials if they are real.

Comment: yeah, i'm having problems, as i said, i'm still new to django and i'm not really getting how to change the languages, i searched all over Google, like i said, i tried to combine some answers, i also gave a read to django docs but still can't quite get it, i've never done internasionalization on a website before haha 

but the thing is, even i was using ONLY the form, it would still get only pt-br, and that's when i tried testing other things!

the form and the view are not related, they are different approaches i was testing

Comment: you think i should keep the set_language view approach and correct the session key?

i'm really sorry if i'm seeming a bit dumb, i'm still learning ): i'm only asking here because i was really out of ideas!